# Deploying ARM templates via Azure Runbooks

Tags: azure, azure-runbook

Im following the Microsoft docs to deploy templates into azure with runbooks , however I cant see where the parameters come from for the script under the heading :
**Create the PowerShell runbook script**

The full guide is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-deploy-template-runbook

```
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]
$ResourceGroupName,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]
$StorageAccountName,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]
$StorageAccountKey,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]
$StorageFileName
```

)

Answer (score 1):

> however I cant see where the parameters come from for the script under the heading.

If we follow the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-deploy-template-runbook) and [Import and publish the runbook into your Azure Automation account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-deploy-template-runbook),**when we try to run the runbook, then we need the input the parameters that required**.

[image]

**Test result:**
[image]

Comment: Many Thanks. When I was testing I did not publish it , I just clicked on TEST Pane so the parameters were not being asked for. As you correctly say it needs to be published first before those parameters are visible!