# Edit runbook content and publish this content by ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-automation, azure-deployment

Currently, I want to create a runbook and edit content with available Python code in local, Then publish this runbook.
How to do it by ARM template ?

Answer (score -1):

**1**. Here is the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual-python-3), which will help you create Runbook and edit the content using Python. You can directly edit the code of the runbook using the text editor in the Azure portal.

- Create a simple Python runbook
- Test and publish the runbook
- Run and track the status of the runbook job
- Update the runbook to start an Azure virtual machine with runbook parameters

**2**. And here is the other [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-deploy-template-runbook) which can show you how to deploy runbook using ARM template

- An Azure Automation account with at least one user-assigned managed identity.
- Az modules: `Az.Accounts`, `Az.ManagedServiceIdentity`, `Az.Resources`, and `Az.Storage`. imported into the Automation account.
- Azure Storage account in which to store the Resource Manager template.
- Azure PowerShell installed on a local machine.  You'll also need module `Az.ManagedServiceIdentity` is a preview module and not installed as part of the Az module. To install it, run `Install-Module -Name Az.ManagedServiceIdentity`

Also, check the Related documents for deploying ARM template.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.automation/automationaccounts/runbooks?tabs=bicep

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49272833